# Delegates with three viewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode

So I have 3 views as follows: viewController >> viewController2 >> viewController3.
In viewController3 I have created a Delegate Protocol. The protocol method is a simple method that prints out an NSLog.

When I call the delegates from ViewController3, only its parent (viewController2 ) responds not the (first) viewController. There are no errors.I think problem has got something to do with [v2 setDelegate:self]; in the viewController.m file.
Nevertheless,[self.v3 setDelegate:self]; works fine in ViewController2.m file.

Why does the (first) viewController delegate not respond ? Do delegates only work with its immediate child ??

```
> **ViewController.h**
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "ViewController2.h"
   #import "ViewController2.h"
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <PassData>{

    ViewController2 *v2;
   }
   @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController2 *v2;

> Blockquote

    - (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
    @end

> **ViewController.M**

    #import "ViewController.h"

   @interface ViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation ViewController
   @synthesize v2;

    - (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    v2 = [[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [v2 setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:v2.view];
    }

    -(void)print: (BOOL)success;{

    if (success == YES) {
        NSLog(@"ViewController called");
    }

    }

    @end

> > ViewController2.h

   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
   #import "ViewController3.h"

    @interface ViewController2 : UIViewController <PassData> {

    ViewController3 *v3;

     }
     @property (strong, nonatomic)ViewController3 *v3;
     @property (retain) id delegate;

   - (IBAction)button:(id)sender;
     @end

   ViewController2.m

   #import "ViewController2.h"

    @interface ViewController2 ()

     @end

    @implementation ViewController2
   @synthesize v3,delegate;

     - (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    v3 = [[ViewController3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
    [self.v3 setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:v3.view];

     }

    -(void)print: (BOOL)success;{

    if (success == YES) {
          NSLog(@"ViewController2 called");
    }
    }
     @end

> ViewController3.h

   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @protocol PassData <NSObject>

    @required

    -(void)print:(BOOL)success;

    @end

    @interface ViewController3 : UIViewController {

    id<PassData>  delegate;

     }

    @property (retain) id delegate;

   - (IBAction)callButton:(id)sender;

    @end

     ViewController3.m

    #import "ViewController3.h"

    @interface ViewController3 ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController3
    @synthesize delegate;

    - (IBAction)callButton:(id)sender {

    // call all delegates
      [[self delegate]print:YES];

     }
    @end
```

Comment: Code in your question is not formatted well (many empty lines) and hard to read. First guess would be, that when you set the delegate for a second time you override the first setting. One delegate ivar can ofcourse hold only one reference.

Comment: @Andrey - umm... i think you are right - the setDelegate is being overridden.  If thats the case, how can the delegate method be called in 2 or more different viewControllers at the same time. My understanding is - that for a viewController to be a delegate, one of the things it must implement is setDelegate.???? does that make sense ??

Comment: @pete are you asking me or rokjarc?

Comment: @Andry - sorry, I meant you.

Comment: @rokarc - sorry, I really am half a sleep here. Again, I meant to ask you - please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v2 doesn't have a method "print", that's a protocol method of v3 -- you can't chain delegate messages like this. If you want multiple controllers to respond to something in another controller, then you should use an NSNotification -- any number of objects can register to receive a notification.

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer is very precise and straight to the point. Now I can move on to learning all about NSNotification. Thanks again.